# Excel: match in a column with another column based on a non blank value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 arrays. The first array lists account nr's with the company name and a column that tracks if they were active last month (marked with an x). The second array has two column; one with only company names and another that needs to be marked with an x if the company is present in the first array in January.

Objective: I want to track active companies in January. To do this, I want to mark the second column in array 2 for all companies that have an 'x' in 'active Jan' in array 1.

Array 1

| Name Company[1] | account nr. | active Jan |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | x |
| B | 321 |  |
| B | 132 | x |

Array 2

| Name Company[2] | active Jan |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| B |  |

What I tried: formula in [array 2,column 2] that gives the value in [array1,column 3] based on a match between name company in array 1 and array 2:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@NameCompany[2]],'array1'!A3:C5,3,FALSE),"")`

Result: This gives the first blank or x values of a company in array1. I need to only give an 'x' in [array2,column2] if there is an x in ]array1,column3], instead of copying the first value in [array1,column3] the formula comes across.
For example, the formula above would give a 0 value (or blank) for company B instead of an x because there are multiple accounts from company B. Ideally, the formula should search only companies with an 'x' in [array1,column3] and then put an 'x' in [array2,column2].

I know I use the wrong formula to reach my objective but I can't find the right one in google/stackoverflow. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('array1'!$A$3:$A$5=[@[Name Company'[2']]])*('array1'!$C$3:$C$5="x")) > 0
```

Comment: You are an absolute hero! I knew there was a good solution but you gave it in just a few minutes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

i've already to chehck it, and found what u want

please try to use my Formula

```
=IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(A11,$A$2:$C$5,3))=0," ",VLOOKUP(A11,$A$2:$C$5,3))
```